# Android: How to override Tooltip in Google Map to include URL

Tags: android

How can i include a URL in my tooltip in Google Map? Thanks

Here is an image of what exactly i require:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must extend [Overlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) and implement it's `draw(..)` method. Some examples: [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html), [here](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/03/steps-to-place-marker-in-map-overlay.html)

Comment: This is not what exactly i'm looking for. I have several close locations that i need to pinpoint on google map by means of a bubble(drawable) in android. When the user clicks that bubble i need a tooltip to be displayed that shows the location and a custom url. Thanks

Comment: Extend `ItemizedOverlay`. Instantiate it with a custom icon (bubble). Override it's `onTap(..)` method to show a custom drawable (tooltip).

Comment: To create a custom drawable take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: Di i have to place my map and draw the tooltip in a webview as i havae to have an active link to be displayed inside it as show in the image below my question? thanks

Comment: I want my tooltip to include a an active url link. Would it be possible in a MapView? Or do i have to place my MapView inside a WebView forthis purpose.

Comment: You can make a Button look like a HTML link. Use Html.fromHtml() to convert raw HTML into a `Spanned` object. Then pass it to a setText() call on a button which you can use in your custom Overlay.